# Reactnative Signalwire application unable to establish Ice server peer connection

Tags: react-native, webrtc, videocall, react-relay, signalwire

I am trying to implement **Signalwire** calling in a react-native app. I am facing issue in connecting ice servers. Sometimes it connects and calling between two persons get successful. But most of the time it throws error

```
"Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'onicecandidate')"
```

I have tried to search a lot but could not succeed. Can you please guide me how this issue can be resolved?  I am using following iceservers:

```
iceServers = [
    {urls: ['stun:stun.l.google.com:19302','stun:stun1.l.google.com:19302','stun:stun2.l.google.com:19302']}
];
```

I have tried to find iceserver associated with my signalwire account but could not find, Please guide me how to get ice/turn/stun server urls and credentials. I am using Relay SDK for reactnative

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible from this post to tell if you're using the SignalWire SDKs exclusively, if you're working from third party tools, or if you're doing your own setup. There are also a few variables in terms of how you've set up your app, what errors you're seeing from the SignalWire side, and the config of your ice servers.

With all that in mind, if you could reach out to SignalWire support (from your SignalWire space, select 'Help and Support' at the top right and then Submit a New Support Request) we can take a look at your setup and work through this with you.